# Set data attribute in jquery each loop

Tags: jquery, each

I have a simple page:

```
<div>test 1</div>
<div>test 2</div>
<div>test 3</div>
<div>test 4</div>
<div>test 5</div>
```

the jQuery script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.each($('div'), function (index, item) {
        $(item).data('testdata', index);
    });

});
```

Here is the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yfo8m93g/

I loop through the div containers to add a data attribute to each one.
However, when I inspect the page after running the fiddle, I do not see the data attributes in the DOM.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.attr()`

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.each($('div'), function (index, item) {
        $(item).attr('data-testdata', index);
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yfo8m93g/6/

Comment: That's not even how data attributes work.

Comment: @Scimonster What? This is certainly a valid use case.

Comment: Data attributes are of the style `data-testdata="something"`.

Comment: @Scimonster You're correct. I misjudged my result. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: right answer now :)  +1